# Clipping file geodatabase vector layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, clip, file-geodatabase

I have a Vector layer loaded from a .gdb (geodatabase directory). I'm seeing my contour lines fine.

- I've drawn a polygon on top of the area I want to crop on a new
  layer.
- I select Geoprocessing Tools > Clip.
- I input my .gdb layer as the Input Vector Layer and choose my new polygon layer, "block" as the clip layer. I save the file to the canvas and to the Output Shapefile, but nothing appears on the final drawing.

How might I go about cropping the feature class in this .gdb?

If I have to save it to a .shp file, how can I only convert the window view into the shapefile, rather than the entire layer?

Comment: Are the two layers in the same coordinate reference system?

Comment: As @Freight_Train mentioned, you can specify the CRS of your new polygon layer. Make sure this is the same as your .gdb layer (you can check this by _right-clicking the layer > Layer Properties > General > Coordinate Reference System_).

Comment: What kind of polygon have you drawn?  If it is just a graphic picture, then the Clip will not work, because it needs a polygon with the same  real-world coordinates as the contour layer (as Freight_Train and Joseph have stated!).  But if you create a GIS polygon layer (such as a shapefile) in the same coordinate system as the contour lines, then you could digitize ("draw") the polygon with the contours as a screen backdrop to help guide where the polygon boundaries should go.  After saving the new polygon, it will be aligned in the same coordinate space as the contours, ready for clipping.